# Split Rectangle in Categories of sub rectangles

Tags: algorithm

Given a rectangle i would like to split it in a given amount n of sub-rectangles where:

- a is the amount of subrectangles which should have a defined z SMALL area
- b is the amount of subrectangles which should have a defined y MEDIUM area
- c is the amount of subrectangles which should have a defined x BIGGER area
  may be I should be able to define d and e . But let's leave them for now.

With "defined area" i mean the geometric area should be the same but the rectangles could have different shape.
May I ask ..which algorithm would You suggest to apply in this case.

I should have a function like this PSEUDO code:

```
RectBoundaries[] function getRectangles(screenRectangle, amountOfRectangleCategories, amountOfRectanglesPerCategory[]) {
   function1 => getRectanglesForCategory1(amountOfRectanglesPerCategory[0], screenRectangle)
   function2 => getRectanglesForCategory2(amountOfRectanglesPerCategory[1], screenRectangle)
   function3 => getRectanglesForCategory3(amountOfRectanglesPerCategory[2], screenRectangle)

   return function1 + function2 + function3;
}
```

EDITED:
How to split a rectangle in multiple (defined amount of) categories of decreasing smaller rectangles.

Comment: Please share your "thinking" about the algorithm, and what your actual question about it is.

Comment: Well. I'm not thinking , i'm asking. How to split a rectangle in multiple (defined amount of) categories of decreasing smaller rectangles.

Comment: Please provide example(s) of input & expected output; your specification is woefully under-specified (impossible to code against "relatively and undefined").

Comment: Is it better now ?

Comment: Please provide example(s) of input & expected output.

Comment: Pseudo code added

Comment: Edited a little bit now

Comment: Isn't it a kind of bidimensional knapsack?

Comment: No idea. Just equal sized rectangles divided in categories

Comment: Please provide example(s) of input & expected output.

Answer (score 1):

By your question I understand you first split your main area in 3 area. One big, one medium and one small. Given this I made a small algo in Javascript, hope it solve your problem

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("output");
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)';

function draw(rect) {
  ctx.rect(rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function splitArea(rect, nbRect) {
  let [nbColumns, nbLines] = getBestRatio(nbRect);
  let x=rect[0];
  let y=rect[1];
  let width = rect[2]/nbColumns;
  let height = rect[3]/nbLines;
  let result = new Array();

  
  for(let i=0; i<nbLines; i++) {
    for(let j=0; j<nbColumns; j++) {
      result.push([x+j*width, y+i*height, width, height]);
    }
  }
  
  return result;
}

function getBestRatio(nb) {
  for(let i=Math.round(Math.sqrt(nb)); i>0; i--) {
    if(nb%i==0) {
      return [i, nb/i];
    }
  }
}

//main rectangle
let rect = [10, 10, 280, 280]; //x, y, width, height

// 3 differents area
let bigArea = [rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3]*2/3]; // 2∕3 area
let mediumArea = [rect[0], rect[1]+rect[3]*2/3, rect[2]*2/3, rect[3]*1/3]; // 2/3 * 1/3 area
let smallArea = [rect[0]+rect[2]*2/3, rect[1]+rect[3]*2/3, rect[2]*1/3, rect[3]*1/3]; // 1/3 * 1/3 area

draw(bigArea);
draw(mediumArea);
draw(smallArea);

splitArea(bigArea, 6).forEach(area => draw(area));
splitArea(mediumArea, 12).forEach(area => draw(area));
splitArea(smallArea, 3).forEach(area => draw(area));
```

```html
<canvas id="output" height="300px" width="300px" style="background-color: grey">
```

Comment: I don't split my area but I want the area of the subrectangles to be the area of small , medium or big . So a group of rectangles with area X . A group of rectangles of area Y and a group with area Z

Comment: But X + Y + Z should Always be equal to the main area, it's not possible to give X, Y and Z since each area depend from others. Maybe your question is not well formulated and you are looking for an algo that, given an area and a sub area, will split the first one in differents rectangles of sub area ?